# How to Solve Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

**I run npm install but this error can not be solved how to solve this error? error code is given below:**

Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: G:\projects\dubole project\Sky-Stars-Client-Side\src\App.js: Unexpected token (20:1)

[0m [90m 18 |[39m [36mimport[39m [33mServiceDetails[39m [36mfrom[39m [32m'./Pages/ServiceDetails/ServiceDetails'[39m[33m;[39m[0m
[0m [90m 19 |[39m [36mimport[39m [33mDefaultDashboard[39m [36mfrom[39m [32m'./Pages/Dashboard/DefaultDashboard'[39m[33m;[39m[0m
[0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 20 |[39m [33m<<[39m[33m<<[39m[33m<<[39m[33m<[39m [33mHEAD[39m[0m
[0m [90m    |[39m  [31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
[0m [90m 21 |[39m [36mimport[39m [33mMakeAdmin[39m [36mfrom[39m [32m'./Pages/Dashboard/MakeAdmin/MakeAdmin'[39m[33m;[39m[0m
[0m [90m 22 |[39m [33m===[39m[33m===[39m[33m=[39m[0m
[0m [90m 23 |[39m [36mimport[39m [33mAllOrders[39m [36mfrom[39m [32m'./Pages/Dashboard/AllOrders/AllOrders'[39m[33m;[39m[0m
at Object._raise (G:\projects\dubole project\Sky-Stars-Client-Side\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:569:17)
at Object.raiseWithData (G:\projects\dubole project\Sky-Stars-Client-Side\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:562:17)
at Object.raise (G:\projects\dubole project\Sky-Stars-Client-Side\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:523:17)
at Object.unexpected (G:\projects\dubole project\Sky-Stars-Client-Side\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3601:16)
at Object.jsxParseIdentifier (G:\projects\dubole project\Sky-Stars-Client-Side\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7282:12)
at Object.jsxParseNamespacedName (G:\projects\dubole project\Sky-Stars-Client-Side\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7292:23)
at Object.jsxParseElementName (G:\projects\dubole project\Sky-Stars-Client-Side\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7303:21)
at Object.jsxParseOpeningElementAt (G:\projects\dubole project\Sky-Stars-Client-Side\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7396:22)
at Object.jsxParseElementAt (G:\projects\dubole project\Sky-Stars-Client-Side\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7429:33)
at Object.jsxParseElement (G:\projects\dubole project\Sky-Stars-Client-Side\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7504:17)
at Object../src/App.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10:7)
at Object.options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48643:31)
at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48093:33)
at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48314:21)
at Module../src/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:322:62)
at Module.options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48643:31)
at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48093:33)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49282:37
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49284:12
./src/App.js @ bundle.js:10
options.factory @ react refresh:6
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/index.js @ store.js:12
options.factory @ react refresh:6
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7

Comment: did you install node.js in your pc from here : https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

try to install babel again and renew your Babel config as such

```
"presets": [
  "@babel/preset-env"
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. now my code is working.